# deserialization of just serialized data fails, why?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xml-deserialization

I am trying to serialize and deserialize objects in silverlight, but cannot seem to get it to work. Serializing works just fine but it complains about my rootObject  not being expected. I don't get it because it it is Silverlight who generated the XML.

Btw; i'm still new to C#

I have a class which looks like:

```
[XmlRoot("DataStorage")] // has no effect
public class DataStorage
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string imgUrl { get; set; }
    public List<AbstractionObject> children { get; set; }

    public DataStorage()
    {
        type = "default";
        children = new List<AbstractionObject>();
    }
}
```

When serialized by Silverlight it produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataStorage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <type>default</type>
  <children />
</DataStorage>
```

However, when I attempt to deserialize it produces:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=`<DataStorage xmlns=''`> was not expected.

My deserialization code is as follows:

```
// create the xmlSerializer for DataObject
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataObject));

// Open the file again for reading.
StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(isoStore.OpenFile("IsoStoreFile.xml", FileMode.Open));
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream);

DataObject deserializedObject = (DataObject)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
fileStream.Close();

Debug.WriteLine(deserializedObject);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this may just be a typo in your example, but the class you've defined in the first block is "DataStorage" and you're serializing and deserializing a "DataObject" which may explains why it's breaking when it encounters "DataStorage".